# How can I keep ViewModel validation in sync with Model validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Entity Framework Code First approach, which means that my Model needs data annotation attributes to create the database. And I do want the validation to be on my Model.

I have some views on my website that can post some information. But this information is not the entire model, and if I was to validate it the validation would fail.

For example I could have a model with these *required* properties: `Title`, `Text`, `X`... But then I could have a view that would only post the value for `Text`. For that I am creating a ViewModel (which also have other elements not attached to the Model). But how would I validate `Text` in this case? I need it to have the same validation as the model property `Text`.

Is there a way to have the **same validations on Model and ViewModel** without duplicating code?

---

This is an attempt that simply wouldn't work...

I thought of creating a custom attribute that would link the validations to the model:

```
/* This wouldn't work */
public class PropertyValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public PropertyValidationAttribute(Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        Type = type;
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var attrs = Type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true) as IEnumerable<ValidationAttribute>;

        if (attrs != null)
        {
            foreach (var attr in attrs)
            {
                return attr.GetValidationResult(value, validationContext);
            }
        }

        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

The issue with the above is that each `ValidationAttribute` can only validate one thing at a time, so if I have multiple validation attributes on my Model it wouldn't work properly. And I am not sure if it would work on Client Side, I didn't even test it...

Comment: I must be missing something.  You say: "*But how would I validate Text in this case? I need it to have the same validation as the model property Text*". What validation is there on the model that you need replicated in the view model?

Comment: I need it in the ViewModel to be able to use client-side validation...

Comment: Can you just apply attributes to both the Model and the ViewModel? Or is that the duplication you're trying to avoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you certainly can work up a solution, you will probably write a lot of code to avoid writing a very small amount of code.

There are things to consider.  First, certain validations are not the same between EF and MVC.  For instance, EF uses MaxLength and MinLength, while MVC uses StringLength.

Second, How are you going to determine which attributes you actually want and don't want?

Finally, there's really only one attribute that maps between.. and that's required.  If you're going to use an attribute to duplicate... well, you've just created just as much code PLUS wrote all the code to do the mapping...

I'd just take the tiny hit and duplicate the mapping in both places...

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection when mapping your model to your viewmodel to check for any validation attributes and then apply those same attributes to your viewmodel. Assuming your property names are the same on both your model and viewmodel you'd be able to create one method that does this.